# Python Read/Write Text Files

Tags: python, text-files

I have a .rtf file containing a unique string on each line, 1000 lines or so. I want to remove the last character off of each of those lines, and output the result into a new .csv file so that I can add it later on into a database.

I tried to do it in python, by opening both files and looping through each line, however the output file would remain empty and I got 0 errors throughout the whole thing. How can I implement another solution in python? Thanks in advance!

```
input_file = "usernames.rtf"
output_file = "outputfile.csv"

character_to_remove = "."

with open(input_file, "r") as input_f, open(output_file, "w") as output_f:
    for line in input_f:
        if line[-1] == character_to_remove:  
          modified_line = line.rstrip(line[-1])
          output_f.write(modified_line + "\n")
        else:
          output_f.write(line + "\n")

input_f.close()
output_f.close()

print("Character removal completed. Check the output file:", output_file)
```

Comment: You should share the code (at least the core part)

Comment: can you show your coding attempt & issue that you are facing?

Comment: yes, @David Guri, you will learn most if you share your attempt and then we can point out where your mistake was

Comment: What is the point of `csv` tag?

Comment: I just added it now

Comment: So if you delete "outputfile.csv" it gets recreated with no content? Is that correct? And ".rtf" sounds like a file in Microsofts "rich text format". Are you sure you want to treat it as a simple text file?

Comment: you use `with` and `open`, why do you call `close()`

Comment: The last character of each line is probably the line termintor `\n` already, so you never find a line ending in full-stop. Try `stripping` the line before testing. Learn the power of the `print` command when facing a `bug` like this. Print it out and the answer is often obvious.

Comment: The output is almost certainly not a valid CSV file.

Comment: Using the shown code, if the input file isn't empty, the output file can't be either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line ends with `'\n'`. So there are two mistakes:

1. You need to replace `character_to_remove = "."` with `character_to_remove = ".\n"`
2. Then you need to replace `line.rstrip(line[-1])` with `line.rstrip(line[-(len(character_to_remove)])`

This would just be a fix for YOUR code. As mentioned, you should use `.readlines()` to avoid such problems. Also, use `line.endswith(<string>)` for your if statement. This function returns True if the string `line` ends with the given string. There is also the equivalent for checking the begin of a string  called `line.startswith(<string>)`.

Edit: This should fit for your problem. As mentioned in some comments, you have to use the right format for a csv file. The csv module, which is part of the standard Python installation, should be enough. Pandas also provides a good csv writing function.

```
import csv  # to create a csv file

input_file = "usernames.rtf"
output_file_txt = "outputfile.txt"
output_file_csv = "outputfile.csv"

character_to_remove = "."

# if you want to remove multiple characters
char_len = len(character_to_remove)

with open(input_file, "r") as input_f, open(output_file_txt, "w") as output_f_txt, open(output_file_csv, "w") as output_f_csv:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(output_f_csv)
    for line in input_f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()  # remove trailing spaces and linebreaks

        if line.endswith(character_to_remove):
          line = line.rstrip(line[-char_len])

        output_f_txt.write(line + "\n")
        csvwriter.writerow(line)  # for further options read csv manual

print("Character removal completed. Check the output file:", output_file_txt, output_file_csv)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read the file first before checking if the character exists in the line with:

```
for line in input_f.readlines():
```

Comment: Using [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) shouldn't change anything. It just has the overhead of creating a list. Could you explain why `readlines` should be better than just iterating over the file?